# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: fclose

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

I have the following program which basically implements a DNS server. Shared memory is used to implement the server cache. I am trying to populate some initial entries to the cache by reading them from a file. But when the file entries go beyond a point, I am getting a segmentation fault. I am unable to debug the program on my own.

```
typedef struct rs{
char domainName[256];
char ip[36];
time_t timeStamp;
struct rs *cacheEnd;
} ResourceRecord;
ResourceRecord *cache, *tempCachePtr, *cacheEnd;
void create_Shared_Memory()         //Creates shared memory 
{
    int stateMemory;
    stateMemory=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, (MAX_CACHE_SIZE)*sizeof(ResourceRecord *),IPC_CREAT|0660);
    if (stateMemory == -1)
    {
            perror("Shared memory creation");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    cache=(ResourceRecord *)shmat(stateMemory,NULL,0);
    tempCachePtr = cache;
    if(shmctl(stateMemory,IPC_RMID,NULL)==-1)
    printf("ERROR CREATING CARMODEMEMORY!!!");

    if(cache==NULL)
    {
        perror("Shared memory attach ");
        shmctl(stateMemory,IPC_RMID,NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
}

void populateCache(){
   tempCachePtr = cache+1;
   struct hostent* domainAddress;
   int i;
   ResourceRecord record;
   char * line = NULL;
   size_t fileInputLength = 0;
   ssize_t read;
   puts("Populating cache");
   FILE *fp = fopen("hosts.txt", "r");
   for(i=1;i<=40; i++){
      if((read = getline(&line, &fileInputLength, fp)) == -1){
        break;
      }
      printf("%d From file %s\n",i, line);
      strcpy(record.domainName, strtok(line, " "));
      strcpy(record.ip, strtok(NULL, "\n"));
      time(&record.timeStamp);
      *tempCachePtr = record;
      tempCachePtr++;
   }
   cacheEnd = tempCachePtr-1;
   *(cache->cacheEnd) = cacheEnd;
   fclose(fp);
}
```

I tried to debug the code using gdb and here is what I have

> symbol lookup error: /home/path/dnsserver: undefined symbol: fclose, version
>   GLIBC_2.2.5 [Inferior 1 (process 7178) exited with code 0177]

and also when I tried to change the number of file entries and debugged again:

> SIGSEGV from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 shared memory

Comment: I don't suppose once that seg-fault hit you managed to take a backtrace?

Comment: @WhozCraig:   No. They are from separate debugging.

Comment: Pardon me, but did you try compiling with `-g` switch enabled?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Yes I did. Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7de3b9b in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Comment: @Unni I'm not very sure about this, but can you please confirm that you're not using any stripped binary? Also, you can try generating the coredump file out of segfault and try running the binary with that one. That may help.

Comment: `sizeof(ResourceRecord *)` is just 4. What is value of `MAX_CACHE_SIZE`? 40?

Comment: @AntoJurković: It is set as 50

Comment: Just guessing: If you want to allocate memory for 50 ResourceRecord than call to `shmget()` is wrong and later on you overwrite that memory. If you want to allocate memory for 50 pointers than it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Anto Jurković, the mistake was that I was creating shared memory using 50*sizeof(ResourceRecord*) where sizeof(ResourceRecord*) is only a few bytes because it was a pointer but sizeof(ResourceRecord) was much bigger (8 and 312 in my system). So 50*sizeof(ResourceRecord*) was only allocating 400 bytes of memory which clearly was not sufficient for 40 ResourceRecord type records.